# Sending HTML data to controller via jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, summernote

I am using summernote and I want to post a part of data to controller; here is how data looks like

```
<p>This is a sample test.&nbsp;</p>
```

Below is the code which I am using

```
var sHTML = $('#summernote').code();
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/GetText",
        data: sHTML,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (vaildText) {
            // So something
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
            // handle error
        }
    });
```

Home Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)] 
    public ActionResult GetText(string sHTML)
    {
        // doing something

        return Json(vaildText);
    }
```

but SHTML on home controller is giving NULL. Where I am wrong? is this is the correct way to post HTML data to controller?

*Stack requested by Arun*

```
    Request URL:http://localhost:23680/Home/GetText
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__AntiXsrfToken=9d34feb94ea546abb4f50eb7251b4e25
Host:localhost:23680
Origin:http://localhost:23680
Referer:http://localhost:23680/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
**Request Payload**
[object Object]
```

Comment: what is sHTML? how is the variable created

Comment: you need to pass the value as a request param... so try the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a request param called sHTML ans pass the value

```
var sHTML = $('#summernote').code();
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/GetText",
    data: {
        sHTML: sHTML
    },
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (vaildText) {
        // So something
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
        // handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: I am still getting null in controller. Do I have to change string sHTML to something else or am I doing some other mistake?

Comment: can you check the request using browser's developer tools and see what are the params sent

Comment: in console I am not getting any error. I don't know how to check params on developers tool (i am googling it now)

Comment: Here is what I got Request URL:http://localhost:23680/Home/GetText
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:15
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__AntiXsrfToken=9d34feb94ea546abb4f50eb7251b4e25
Host:localhost:23680
Origin:http://localhost:23680
Referer:http://localhost:23680/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
[object Object]

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite not a ASP.NET guy... do you want the request data as request param or as request body

Comment: from summernote, I have extracted some data (which is HTML too). Now I want to send that data (html) to controller and get back the result from database.

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing `contentType: false` and add `datatype` in ajax call as shown :-

```
var sHTML = $('#summernote').code();
$.ajax({
  url: "Home/GetText",
  data: {
    sHTML: sHTML
  },
  type: 'POST',
  datatype:'JSON'
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (vaildText) {
    // So something
  },
  error: function () {
    alert('error');
    // handle error
  }
});
```